# Calling soap web service written in Java from classic asp (using wsse:security)

Tags: java, soap, asp-classic, soapui, wsse

I guess this topic might already be addressed, but I really need someone's help.

I am working on a project developed with classic ASP and now I need to consume a webservice written in java using SOAP. Well I found many articles (including here on SO), teaching how to consume a webservice, using XMLHTTP or with SOAPClient, but this is not the problem. The problem is that the person who created the webservice included a security configuration within the SOAP header. They sent us an XML containing a request model where I saw some information that I don't know exactly how I can send from classic ASP. They also sent the WSDL file that I opened with SOAPUI but I couldn't see the information that I saw in the header. I have created a MOCK inside SOAPUI for testing those methods but I couldn't see it there either.

Here's the XML model request that they sent us:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:impl="http://impl.webservices.rro.bvsistemas.com.br" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
   <soap:Header>
      <wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="true" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
         <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-E4B158BCC4FCBA267D14374818797522">
            <wsu:Created>Timestamp value</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>Timestamp value</wsu:Expires>
         </wsu:Timestamp>
         <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-E4B158BCC4FCBA267D14374818764431">
            <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">Hash value</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>Timestamp value</wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
      </wsse:Security>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      Body content
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So, I need to build a request using SOAP to consume the webservice, and as I said, written in Java, but I need to pass the information in the SOAP header, using classic ASP. Is there some library in classic ASP that would help me build this request structure using SOAP with these tags within the security element?

Thanks.